# How to import 3D Model COLLADA (.dae) file to RVIZ

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-kinetic, collada, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and I am having problems importing a 3D Model of a formula car (COLLADA file) i got from 3D warehouse to RVIZ. This is the COLLADA file:

[FILE](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/bc6d79537b6d5a21210da567d50ade76/Formula-Student-Stuttgart)

This is my code. It is working for a simple cube as marker. Now I wanted to change the cube to this formula car using the marker type "visualization_msgs::Marker::MESH_RESOURCE"

```
visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
marker.header.frame_id = "/my_frame";
marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
marker.ns = "myns";
marker.id = k+current_cone_pos.left.x.size()+current_cone_pos.right.x.size()+1;
marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::MESH_RESOURCE;
marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
marker.mesh_resource = "file://models/v1-01/model.dae";
marker.pose.position.x = 0;
marker.pose.position.y = 0;
marker.pose.position.z = 0;
marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
marker.scale.x = 0.1;
marker.scale.y = 0.5;
marker.scale.z = 0.5;
marker.color.b = 0.0f;
marker.color.g = 0.0f;
marker.color.r = 1.0;
marker.color.a = 1.0;
marker.lifetime = ros::Duration();
visualizer_.publish(marker);
```

The error that i get using "rosrun rviz rviz" while running my C++ Node is:

Could not load resource [file://models/v1-01/model.dae]: Unable to open file "file://models/v1-01/model.dae".

Thank you guys for your support!

Greetings,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267559/how-to-import-3d-model-collada-(.dae)-file-to-rviz/) by [AlexROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/31365/alexros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/90303/david_ros/) on 2021-11-24**:
Hi, Alex, do you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if `models` is a ROS package, then you should use `package://`, not `file://`.

if it's a directory somewhere on your filesystem, use an absolute path (ie: `file:///path/to/where/models/is/..`).

See the documentation for [wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker - Mesh Resource](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) which explains all of this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/31365/alexros/) on 2017-07-28**:
Still not working.

I have tried the absolute path with the following line of code:

marker.mesh_resource = "file://home/alex/catkin_ws/models/v1-01/model.dae";

It still does not work. Do i need any additional urdf file or so? Models ist just a file in which the model is stored, not a ros package

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-28**:
Note the additional `/`: this may seem strange, but `file://` (with two `/`) is the *scheme*, the path starts only after that. So for an absolute path, you need to have three consecutive forward slashes.

**Comment by [AlexROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/31365/alexros/) on 2017-07-28**:
Okay now the error has gone away. But the car is still not visible in rviz

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-28**:
one thing to check: ROS uses meters for everything, so make sure your mesh is scaled to that as well (most exports from 3D modellers are in mm).

**Comment by [AlexROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/31365/alexros/) on 2017-07-28**:
I tried to set the scale parameters to 1000. But that still does not solve the problem. :-/ Did you have a look at the link of the formula car? Is the file format suitable? Do i need an urdf file maybe?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-28**:
Let's eliminate some variables here: try to get things to work with a very simple Collada file (a cube with a single colour). Once that works, we can look at the car model.

**Comment by [AlexROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/31365/alexros/) on 2017-07-28**:
It worked with this simple cube: [LINK]
(https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/b3e0972ece48c304664cc17fe2c6413a/Yla-Eason-double-cube)

So maybe it is because of the texture that the car has. I tried to do this with the car:

marker.mesh_use_embedded_materials = true;

But it didnt help.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-08-01**:
Try installing Meshlab. Import the dae then export it as binary.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the `visualization_msgs` markers of **RViz** I wrote a small package that makes it easy to **load meshes into RViz** as textured objects.

It simply loads all files which were put inside its meshes folder and **publishes them to the** `visualization_marker` topic. And even **dynamically**! When a new object is added to the folder, it appears (or is published) in RViz. If an object is deleted, it also disappears from the published models.

It also contains a launch file which just takes everything which is inside the meshes folder, opens up RViz with a suitable perspektive and visualizes the 3D files.

Just check it out here: https://github.com/vonunwerth/RVizMeshVisualizer

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) with karma: 66 on 2022-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2